# How to display login error message one after another

Tags: angularjs

I am supposed to check if my login has an error it will display "invalid username. then, the second login will display " server busy" and third login will redirect to link dashboard.html

However, my codes below ignore the error message and continue to dashboard.html.

How am i supposed to loop the statement so that the error will display accordingly.

```
postData.data._class = postData.clazz;
        $timeout(function (data,status) {
          $scope.isLoading = false;
          if ($scope.hasError = false){

            $scope.errorMessage = "Invalid username or password. Error code = " + status;
            console.log($scope.errorMessage)
          }
         }, 2000);

         $timeout(function (data,status) {
           $scope.isLoading = false;
           if ($scope.hasError = true){

             $scope.errorMessage = "Server busy please try again later. Error code = " + status;
             console.log($scope.errorMessage)
           }
          }, 2000);

         $timeout(function (data,status) {
            $scope.isLoading = false;
            if ($scope.hasError = true){

               $window.location.href = "/dashboard.html";
            }
          }, 2000);
```

Comment: Can you elaborate on first, next and third login?

Comment: i need to display different error message for different login @nikhil

Comment: Different login means? How are you segregating logins?

Comment: $timeout is not a good option

Comment: let say my first login gives an error "invalid". then the second time of login will not give the "invalid" message and it will proceed to "server busy" message @nikhil

Comment: i used timeout to change login button to logging in button in 2 seconds time. @Kailas

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If my understanding is correct, then you want to have 3 different results when user triggers the login function with error scenario that can be due to invalid credentials or some other issue.

If that is correct, then you can do something like following

You will need to maintain a counter that defines the attempt.

```
$scope.counter = 0; // This should be outside the event handler function

$timeout(function (data,status) {
      $scope.isLoading = false;
      if ($scope.hasError){
          if($scope.counter == 0) {
              $scope.errorMessage = "Invalid username or password. Error code = " + status;
              console.log($scope.errorMessage);
              $scope.counter++; 
          } else if($scope.counter == 1) {
              $scope.errorMessage = "Server busy please try again later. Error code = " + status;
              console.log($scope.errorMessage);
              $scope.counter++; 
          } else {
             $window.location.href = "/dashboard.html";
         }
      }
     }, 2000);
```

**Please note**: `$scope.hasError = true` is assignment and NOT comparison.

Comment: It must be because earlier you were assigning `$scope.hasError` to `true` in your `if` condition. Now, because of the changes done, the `if` block must not be getting executed as `$scope.hasError` must be either `undefined` or `false`. Please check again.

Comment: If only invalid error is coming then just try to make sure where have you initialized the `$scope.counter = 0`. It seems it is in the event handler itself i.e. everytime the counter is reset to 0